# Excel: convert IMAGE cell to txt cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, string

I download an excel file from web.
In this DB file I have photo linked to some records but in the file each photo is linked in an IMAGE cell. I would like to insert the name of the photo instead IMAGE.

This is the structure of the IMAGE cell:

```
=COLLEG.IPERTESTUALE("https://webserver.com/file/568/attachment/FILENAMEdotjpg";"IMAGE")
```

I would like to show only `FILENAME.jpg`

Comment: There are many text formulas in excel that can pull just the file name from the image cell text. Try them first,

Comment: Could you please suggest me one? The original file come from a web download and I have many cells to "convert". I am not able to use text formulas because excel read "IMAGE" instead of the long string "=colleg.ipertestuale(..........)"

Comment: start with `=FORMULATEXT()`, it should give you the string so you can manipulate it further.